# Get previous trade profit percentage in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to obtain the previous trade profit percentage before opening a new trade, like showed in the list of trades sub-tab on the strategy tester.

[image: img trades]

I've tried...

```
profit = strategy.netprofit
profitChange = roc(profit, 50)
```

but I'm getting strange results... it had to be 7,66

[image]

any tips?

Answer (score 1):

This was not thoroughly tested and will most probably work only for simple entry/exit scenarios:

```
//@version=4
strategy("BarUpDn Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 10, precision = 6)
// Issue long/short on bar up/dn and gap conditions.
enterLong  = close > open and open > close[1]
enterShort = close < open and open < close[1]
if enterLong
    // On the close of the bar, place order for long entry and 
    strategy.entry("Long executed", strategy.long)
    alert("Long order placed")
if enterShort
    strategy.entry("Short executed", strategy.short)
    alert("Short order placed")

changeInProfits = change(strategy.netprofit)
lastPercentProfit = changeInProfits ? 100 * (changeInProfits / strategy.position_size[1]) / strategy.position_avg_price[1] : na
plotchar(lastPercentProfit, "lastPercentProfit", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)

// For validation
plotchar(strategy.netprofit, "strategy.netprofit", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(strategy.position_size, "strategy.position_size", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(strategy.position_avg_price, "strategy.position_avg_price", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

Comment: good script but i would say corret way to compute profit (%) is: close[0]/strategy.position_avg_price

Comment: The OP's request was to obtain the profit from the last trade.

Comment: is it possible to get profit of certaion position? eg i have two opened orders how to get opened profit of first order? strategy.position_avg_price[1] isn't the solution or? aha i see it might be like this - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(order_num) but only in v5